# Does a Moldovan citizen require a visa to travel to India?

Tags: visas, india, moldovan-citizens

I am a citizen of Moldova and will be travelling to India sometime in December. I'm planning to stay there for a couple of weeks.

Do I need a tourist visa to travel to India and, if so, what is the process for applying for a visa?

Answer (score 1):

Moldovan citizens require a [tourist](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=MD&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IN&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) [visa](https://india.visahq.com/requirements/moldova/) to travel to India and are unable to use their e-Tourist Visa.  The application process can be started [online](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/).